# Storing 7 numbers of user inputs in different slots in a list

Tags: python, list

```
print("Type in the 7 digits") 
(7D)=list(7D)

(7D)=int(input([0]))
(7D)=int(input([1]))
(7D)=int(input([2]))
(7D)=int(input([3]))
(7D)=int(input([4]))
(7D)=int(input([5]))
(7D)=int(input([6]))

print(7d)
```

I am trying to make a program that lets the user enter 7 digits simealtaneously while storing the each digit different slots in a list.

e.g user types 1601732
program has to store 1 as 7D([0]),6 as 7D([1])...

Comment: `(7D)` does not make sense in Python.  `7D` is not a valid variable name.  `7d` just adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept a single string, you can already access it as a list, since a string is also a sequence

```
>>> s = input('enter 7 digits: ')
enter 7 digits: 1352468
>>> s
'1352468'
>>> s[0]
'1'
>>> s[3]
'2'
```

You can also interpret it as a number for calculations

```
>>> int(s)
1352468
>>> int(s[1])
3
```

Comment: Access it *like* a list, not *as* a list.

Comment: @zondo that is what I said. A string is not a list, but both are "sequences" so they share those semantics, eg slicing, indexing, etc. Edit: oh I see, my specific phrasing, okay :)

Answer (score 1):

```
typed = raw_input("Type in 7 digits: ")
digits_list = [ ]
count = 0
for i in typed:
    digits_list.append(typed[count])
    count +=1
```

## print digits_list to check. I believe this is what you wanted :)

Comment: why are you appending `typed[count]` instead of `i`? Or using `for count in range(len(typed))`? Better yet, why don't you do `digit_list = list(typed)`?

Comment: I'm still learning. I can only do things the way I conceptualize them. The more code I read the more I learn, the better I get.

Comment: Alright, but after looking over your code again do you understand why `typed[count]` will always be the same as `i`?

Comment: I do realize that. It may seem silly but by the persons example that is what he was looking for. typed[count] increments so it represents a different index in the list as his digit increments.                                                                                                    >>> s = input('enter 7 digits: ')
        enter 7 digits: 1352468
>>> s
'1352468'
>>> s[0]
'1'
>>> s[3]
'2'    just as this person above answered it comes out to be the same.